oidc-provider: how to add custom claims to /me endpoint and returned access token
I would like my /me endpoint to return specific custom claims as well as the data contained in my access token body.  I have tried the following approach to no avail.
...,
    formats: {
        AccessToken: 'jwt',
    },
claims: {
        custom: ['custom_field_1', 'custom_field_2', 'custom_field_3', 'custom_field_4']
    },
findAccount: async (ctx, sub, token) => {
        const user = await retrieveAccount({id: sub});

        return {
            accountId: sub,
            claims: async (use, scope, claims, rejected) => {
                return {
                    sub,
                    custom_field_1: user.custom_field_1,
                    custom_field_2: user.custom_field_2,
                    custom_field_3: user.custom_field_3,
                    custom_field_4: user.custom_field_4
                };
            }
        }
    }

When I look at the response in the network section of the browser, I only see the sub field listed in the json body for the /me endpoint.  What am I missing here for the /me to not display the custom fields in the json body?  Also, what would I need to do to get the custom fields in the jwt body as well?
